# Can't wrap an image in the bootstrap card class (using wagtail)

Tags: bootstrap-4, wagtail

I'm currently testing wagtail and came across one problem. I have a model like this

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.wagtailimages.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

class PostPage(Page):

    body = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+',
        blank=True, null=True
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname='full'),
        ImageChooserPanel('photo'),
    ]
```

through the wagtail admin page I enter some text using CharField and add photo using ForeignKey (just like in wagtail tutorial). But then I want to wrap the data that I've entered into the bootstap code like this in my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-postpage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{{ page.title }}<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{ page.body }}</button>
<br>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src={% image page.photo width-300 %} alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% image page.photo width-400 %}

{% endblock %}
```

The problem is the I can actually wrap my page.body into bootstrap "button" class, but when it comes to the picture it is not rendered in the page when I want, for example, to wrap it into bootstrap "card" class.
The picture is shown in the page when I just use normal code like this 
`{% image page.photo width-400 %}`,but it doesn't appear when I use this code inside bootstrap "card" class.
The bootstrap itself working fine on the page. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{% image page.photo width-300 %}` tag outputs a complete `<img ...>` element in the resulting page, so using that *inside* an `<img>` element will result in the following output which clearly isn't valid HTML:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src=<img src="some-url.jpg"> alt="Card image cap">
```

There are two routes you can take here, described at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/images.html?highlight=img#more-control-over-the-img-tag:

- Pass the `class` attribute required by Bootstrap as part of the `{% image %}` tag:

  ```
  {% image page.photo width-400 class="card-img-top" %}
  ```

  (You don't need to supply `alt` here, as `{% image %}` provides that already)
- Use `{% image .. as foo %}` to store the relevant image properties (such as URL) into a variable, so that you can then insert those properties into the `<img>` element individually:

  ```
  {% image page.photo width-400 as card_image %}

  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src={{ card_image.url }} alt="Card image cap">
  ```